# How to get the last character of a string by coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, string, coffeescript

I have a string as below:

```
str = "abcdefg123"
```

I want to get the last character(3), how to make it by coffeescript?

I am a newcomer to coffeescript, hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enjoy some Coffeescript [destructuring assignement](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) and [splats](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

```
str = "abcdefg123"
[..., lastChar] = str
alert lastChar
```

Answer (score 6):

As in JavaScript:

```
str[str.length-1]
str.slice -1
```

or, using a range:

```
str[-1..-1]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kma96e6h/1/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice helper for you

```
String::last = ->
  @slice -1
```

Then you can do:

```
"Pizza".last()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What is the meaning for `@slice -1`?

Comment: `@` is a shortut for `this` so `@slice` means `this.slice`. And -1 because javascript is nice, if you give a negative index to `slice`, it'll slice from the end of the string/array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this in CoffeeScript, but in vanilla Javascript you could just do the following.

```
str.substring(str.length - 1);
```

Or even

```
str[str.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
str[str.length - 1]
=> '3'
```

or:

```
str.slice(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I miss the answers:

coffee:

`str[-1..]` (or `str[-n..]` for the last n chars)

and plain

`str.substr(-1)`   (or `str.substr(-n)`)